# Unknown option argument: "--multiprocessing-fork"

Tags: vim, python

I have an error on Windows vim version 7.4.417 (no problems on Linux): Unknown option argument: "--multiprocessing-fork" . It is related to using python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). How can I fix that?

Comment: How is Vim invoked, is that argument passed to it? Vim never understood this.

Comment: No arguments were passed to Vim.

Comment: I don't understand how pymode or rope passes this argument to Vim, but [this GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/issues/422) makes it look like this has to do with using HEAD by default; try using commit 20e14aa as it says in that thread. (I don't know if there's a newer commit that would also work, but it's worth investigating.)

Comment: What are you talking about? I did not say that I use pymode or rope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to fix this. There is no parallelization in vim python plugins. Python threads are not parallelizable, because of GIL. And vim does not work with python multiprocessing module (https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?can=1&start=300&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=302).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the answer to this was at the time it was asked, but on python 3.9, you can edit your .vimrc and put this somewhere near the top:

```
python3 << EOF
import sys
import multiprocessing.spawn
py_exec_path = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'python.exe')
multiprocessing.spawn.set_executable(py_exec_path)
EOF
```